# div in Safari browser full height of page

Tags: css, safari

This page is fine in Firefox, but in Safari the 'inside' div takes up the full height of the page leaving the 'buy tickets' link un-clickable, and the copy text on the page un-selectable.

Can anybody help with this?

http://www.scoundrelscomedyclub.co.uk/?cat=2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the css of the class inside:

```
.inside{
/*Other css stuff */
z-index:-10; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index of 1 to the post-meta div:

```
.post-meta {
    z-index:1;
}
```

This way, it will be 'on top' off the other div's.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Did it work your end?